# Javascript array notation on object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to know how this works behind the scenes: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

How does JQuery set up `foo[0]` to execute the `get` function. I had a look at the source code but all I found was this:

```
get: function( num ) {
    return num != null ?

        // Return just the one element from the set
        ( num < 0 ? this[ num + this.length ] : this[ num ] ) :

        // Return all the elements in a clean array
        slice.call( this );
},
```

How can I my own object so that accessing an array index calls a function like this?

I'd like to do the same thing:

```
myObj[0];
```

acts identically to

```
myObj.get(0);
```

Looking a JQuery this must be possible as it doesn't just set `this[0] = 'whatever'` for each index manually, it executes the .get function somehow. Is there a way to say whenever an array lookup is made, to execute a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in jQuery `0` is the key of the property in the object which holds the DOMElement. This means that you're actually accessing an object by key, not an array by index. The `get()` method is just a wrapper for that accessor. Here's a working example:

```js
var obj = {
    '0': 'hello!',
    get: function(key) {
     return this[key];
    }
};

console.log(obj[0]);
console.log(obj.get(0));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

> How does JQuery set up foo[0] to execute the get function

It's the other way round. `get(0)` simply calls `[0]`.

jQuery creates an array-like stack of element objects, so it follows that, to extraxt one, you can use array syntax, e.g. `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

After realising the JQuery method would not work for me as I wanted to execute code on the call I found a solution using Proxy objects:

```
var p = new Proxy(Obj, {
   get(target, name, receiver) {
    console.log(name);
    return name;
   }
});
```

`p[0]`will print `0` and allow executing code inside the function. I'm not sure if this will work in all browsers but this is for a node project.